# xrdp with sesman for port redirection

Tags: xinetd, xrdp

I am using xrdp in Centos.

1) in /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini I set the port to -1

```
[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
```

This is ok.  I can login with my user and password.

1) in /etc/xrdp/sesman.ini I want to redirect to port 5902

port 5902: where my vncserver is already running in Xinetd.

How would you configure the sesman.ini to connect to these port 5902?

Answer (score 0):

try to config /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini, and set port as 5902

```
[xrdp1]
name=sesman-Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=5902
```